# How to delete a database using node.js and MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to MongoDB and node.js and I want to know how to delete a database.
I've searched for and I found that it is done with the `dropDatabase()` method. The problem is that it shows a `MongoError:  user is not allowed to do action [dropDatabase] on [test.]`. I also searched for this error and the answer I found is that the user needs to be registered as `Data Access Read Write`. However, my user in  mongo atlas is registred as `Project Owner` and as the answer says. I removed `Project Owner` and it still displays the error.

```
MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected...");
    const db = client.db("test");
    db.dropDatabase();
    console.log("asdfghj")
    client.close();
});
```

In fact, whenever i searched to fix the problem typing `Mongo atlas` in the search bar, the results are like `How to delete cluster in mongo atlas` even though i'm typing `delete database in mongo atlas`. So i don't know if a database can be deleted in mongo atlas.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are confusing "Atlas Project" security with "Database Access".

If you are looking for removing a database from an Atlas Cluster, the "Database User" you are using to login in your Mongo Client needs to have "dbAdmin" role in the related database. You can then perform related operations using your database user via your Mongo client programmatically.

You can refer to https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/ for managing database users and security roles.

Answer (score -1):

You can log into Atlas, click the cluster name, click the "collections" tab, then when you hover over the database name on the left, there will appear a garbage can icon, which will delete the DB (assuming your user has proper permissions)

If you want to delete the db in code, there's no way to do it directly from mongoose, but you can if you access the underlying mongodb driver:

`mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(cb)`

Comment: Yeah, but isn't there a way to delete it with code?

Comment: You can manage your databases and collections via Atlas UI but this is not the approach you would follow for managing your databases programmatically.